# How can I work with .img/.hdr data in Python?

Tags: python, medical

I have some MRI scans files of extention `.img/.hdr/.gif`. I am completely new to it.

How can I work with it? How can I look at a slice of MRI scan in that '.img' array?

I've found

```
import nibabel as nib
img = nib.load('./OAS1_0001_MR1_mpr_n4_anon_111_t88_masked_gfc_fseg.img')
print(img)
```

Which shows

```
<class 'nibabel.spm2analyze.Spm2AnalyzeImage'>
data shape (176, 208, 176, 1)
affine: 
[[  -1.     0.     0.    87.5]
 [   0.     1.     0.  -103.5]
 [   0.     0.     1.   -87.5]
 [   0.     0.     0.     1. ]]
metadata:
<class 'nibabel.spm2analyze.Spm2AnalyzeHeader'> object, endian='>'
sizeof_hdr     : 348
data_type      : b'\x00B\x00\x00YA\x00\x00\xe8@'
db_name        : b'\x00\x00\x14@\x00\x00\x9d?\x00\x00\xbf>\x00\x005>'
extents        : 16384
session_error  : 0
regular        : b'r'
hkey_un0       : b' '
dim            : [  4 176 208 176   1   0   0   0]
vox_units      : b'mm'
cal_units      : b'7\x00\x00\x006\x16'
unused1        : 0
datatype       : uint8
bitpix         : 8
dim_un0        : 0
pixdim         : [  0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00
   1.65311180e-41   1.60658869e-41   1.55614194e-41   1.50821754e-41]
vox_offset     : 0.0
scl_slope      : nan
scl_inter      : 0.0
funused3       : 0.0
cal_max        : 0.0
cal_min        : 0.0
compressed     : 0
verified       : 0
glmax          : 3
glmin          : 0
descrip        : b'                                                                               '
aux_file       : b'                       '
orient         : b''
origin         : [8224 8224 8224 8224 8192]
generated      : b'         '
scannum        : b'         '
patient_id     : b'         '
exp_date       : b'         '
exp_time       : b'         '
hist_un0       : b'  '
views          : 0
vols_added     : 0
start_field    : 0
field_skip     : 0
omax           : 0
omin           : 0
smax           : 0
smin           : 0
```

But there is no something where I can get slices of MRI scan. How can I plot it? I have assumption that `img.get_data()` should help me...

Answer (score 2):

For plotting you can use

```
from nilearn import plotting
plotting.plot_anat(img, title="plot_anat")
```

and to extract data you are right you can use **img.get_data()**

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the shape of your data (`data shape (176, 208, 176, 1)`, it's a 3D image so you need to specify which plane you want to have plotted in 2D. There are three options:

- Axial or horizontal or transverse plane; divides the body into head and tail (Z-axis)
- Coronal or frontal plane; divides the body into posterior and anterior portions (Y-axis)
- Sagittal or longitudal plane; divides the body into right and left (X-axis)

You can find more details on the anatomical planes in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatomical_plane) along with a very helpful diagram.

So for your data, once you've read it as you describe, you can get out a normal array by calling

`im_data = img.get_fdata()` (I'm getting a depreciation warning for `get_data()`)

The data array will have the same shape so if you want to plot a center slice along one of the planes, you just write:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

center_slice = im_data[:,:,88, 0]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.imshow(center_slice, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```

Note that the image won't necessarily be correctly positioned (rotation, axes, etc.). Sometimes it's enough to rotate it 90 degrees or shift manually using `scipy.ndimage.shift()`. `nilearn plotting` source code has a comprehensive list of transformations and modifications to the default MPL axes so worth a look.